# JavaScript return error message on invalid character input

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I want a text box to only accept alphabetical characters, which I believe is done with the current function I call after each character input. However I also want to return an error message when a user tries to input a character that is not an alphabetical character. Can anyone explain a possible solution to this problem?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    function validateLetter() {
        var textInput = document.getElementById("maiden").value;
        textInput = textInput.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "");
        document.getElementById("maiden").value = textInput;
      }
      /* ]] */
  </script>
</head>

  <body>
    <form action="validateThePassword" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
      <p>Enter mother's maiden name:
        <input type="text" id="maiden" name="maiden" onkeypress="validateLetter()" </p>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Be sure to close your `input` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function:

```
    function validateLetter() {
        var textInput = document.getElementById("maiden").value;
        var replacedInput = textInput.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "");
        if(textInput != replacedInput)
            alert("Error message");

        document.getElementById("maiden").value = replacedInput;
  }
```

and change the input element to:

```
<input id="maiden" name="maiden" onkeyup="validateLetter();" />
```

The variable textInput now contains the input value after the keypress. The function then checks if the post-replacement string is the same as the original input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming alphabetical characters as `[A-Za-z]` you can use RegExp [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function to check if the input as only *alphabetical characters*

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(textInput)
```

This regular expression returns true when from the beginning `^` to the end `$` of `textInput` you only have characters in the `[a-zA-Z]` set (empty string included).

If you want to include the white space to the set:

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(textInput)
```

Applied to your `validateLetter` function:

```
function validateLetter() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("maiden").value;
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(textInput)) {
        // Return error message.
    }
    textInput = textInput.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "");
    document.getElementById("maiden").value = textInput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, naive solution that works for `en-us` at least. It uses the char code value instead of regex to only allow users to type control chars (like `shift`, `alt`, etc.), and only allows alpha chars to even be pressed. It shows an error message if invalid char pressed.

JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/297uvnx2/

Working SO example and source code follows:

```js
var utils = {
    validateLetter: function (event) {
        var c0 = 48;
        var cA = 65;
        var cZ = 90;
        var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');
        var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
        if (key > cZ || (key < cA && key >= c0)) {
            feedback.innerHTML = "That character is not allowed."
            feedback.style.display = "block";
            return false;
        } else {
            feedback.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
};
var txtMaiden = document.getElementById('maiden');
txtMaiden.onkeydown = utils.validateLetter;
txtMaiden.focus();
```

```css
.error {
    display:none;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: rgb(255, 245, 245);
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<p>Mother's maiden name:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="maiden" name="maiden" /><span id="feedback" class="error"></span>

</p>
```